# SwitchCompat not showing on device

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-appcompat

I'm trying to use a SwitchCompat, and it shows up in the Design view in Android Studio, but on my Galaxy S4 (running 5.0.1), it doesn't show up.  Here is relevant code:

activity.xml

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/monitoring_text"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/monitoring_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                app:showText="false"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I finally got it working:

1 - Download the Android Support Repository

2 - Add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to your activity XML

3 - Use AppCompat versions of widgets in your Activities, eg. import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;

4 - Make sure to set your themes in styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml to one of the AppCompat themes.

5 - If you are getting errors, try to invalidate cache and restart so your R resources are reset.